# Accessing a web server on a Mac Virtual Machine from the Mac Host and Network

Tags: webserver

*Initial Config*

- The host machine is OS X 10.10.2
- The Virtual machine is a OS X 10.9.5
- Tomcat v7.0 server (java servlet) is running inside the virtual machine. While on the VM, I can access the website on localhost:8080.

*Steps*

I followed a myriad of different guides, but they all revolve around doing the same sort of thing. So, what I have tried is port forwarding.

1. I ensured that the network adapter setting is set to "Share with my Mac".

[image]

2. I retrieved the IP for the virtual machine using `arp -an` command. THe command returns 2 numbers. I've tried both of them. 
   [image]
3. On the host machine, I have modified the file `/Library/Preferences/VMware Fusion/vmnet8/nat.conf`:

   `[incomingtcp] 
    8080 = 192.168.83.2:8080`

   4. I restarted the VM, but when I try to access the web servlet on the host mac, I get `Safari can't connect to the server`

The firewall is turned off for both of the machines.

Is there some step I'm missing? I've tried using the bridged networking as well, but I'm not as sure of what to do there.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For others to know, this is what I ended up doing:

I selected `Bridged Networking - Autodetect` instead of `Share with Mac`. This option can either be picked through the option mentioned in my question, or also by selecting the menu at the top and selecting `Virtual Machine > Network Adapter > Bridged (Autodetect)`.

Afterwards, inside the Virtual Machine, I opened terminal and typed `ifconfig`. There's an IP mentioned after `inet` in the `en0:` section. That's the IP I can use to access servers running on the Virtual Machine from the network.